# Issue with cytoscape network repeated edges

Tags: cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I am working on a chemical oligomerization reaction network and have generated a Cytoscape network showing each molecular species and intermediate ions in each node and each connecting edge represents a reaction pathway. The issue is, in this system most reactions are reversible and thus two edges are generated between two nodes and there is no reasonable way to edit my network simulation outputs to remove the reverse reactions. Is there a way I can delete the double edges between two nodes without having to do it manually? [An example image of a small section of my network showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dghSB.png)

Comment: cytoscape.js is very different from cytoscape

Answer (score 0):

Is this for the Cytoscape desktop or cytoscape.js?  For Cytoscape desktop, you can collapse multiple edges using the Edit->Remove duplicate edges...

-- scooter